# Recommendations on resigning apk

Tags: android, apk, vendor

We have an external vendor who develops an android app for our organization. We want the apk to be signed with our organizational signature, not the vendor signature, when releasing the app to play store. what are the best recommendations on re-signing the android apk?

Comment: You have to sign the apk with the same key every time you do an update. Im not sure if you can change the info on an existing key. If you lose the key you can not do updates

Comment: If we were to release the apk to play store, what should we be expecting from the vendor?

Comment: Definetly the project with all the files. Android studio the would give you a zip file probably. And the signing key. There are a bunch of different ways to sign these days i think but there should be a signing key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-signing the APK will remove the previous signature, so it will work as you expect it.

Recommendation is to use `apksigner` (released as part of the Android SDK), which offers more secure signing algorithms to sign APKs. The alternative is `jarsigner`, but it's slower for Android devices to verify the signature (so installation takes more time) and it's not as secure.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to build and sign it yourself from the release branch or using the commit hash of the code (that is verified by QA team of external vendor). 
With gradle support in Android projects it is very simple to set up a small script block that will sign the apk with right keys. 
For example, in our projects we have created a properties file like this

```
ANDROID_KEYSTORE_LOCATION=~/.android/debug.keystore
ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=android
ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS=androiddebugkey
ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS_PASSWORD=android
```

You can swap the values in above lines to your release keys when you build in-house, without any modification to gradle script. Of course the vendor has to make a change in gradle build script to read this file.

Comment: this is a smart approach